# facebook pixel в iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook

Есть необходимость создать iframe с загрузкой другого сайта в котором есть fb pixel 
Загрузку я сделал, но проблема со статистикой в пикселе.
Вот например, есть сайт `https://somesite.com/` на этом сайте установлен `iframe` с загрузкой контента с пикселем с сайта `https://pixel.com/`.

В статистике пикселя в фб отображается что пиксель был загружен на сайте `https://somesite.com/`, но он же установлена на сайте `https://pixel.com/` и надо что б отображалось что пиксель загрузился на сайте `https://pixel.com/` а сайт `https://somesite.com/` не попадал в статистику фейсбука. Есть возможность как то так сделать?

Comment: Приведите Ваш код. Что у Вас не получается? Какие действия Вы уже предприняли?

Comment: не получается сделать так что б сайт на где установлен `iframe` не попадал в статистику фейсбука, а в статистике отображался только сайт с пикселем который подгружается через `iframe`